# How to sort EC2 instances from the AWS SDK

Tags: java, sdk, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

I can get a list of my running instances like this

```
   ..
    DescribeInstancesResult describeInstancesRequest = ec2.describeInstances();
    listEC2Reservations = describeInstancesRequest.getReservations();

    Set<Instance> instances = new HashSet<Instance>();
    for (Reservation reservation : listEC2Reservations) {
        instances.addAll(reservation.getInstances());      
    }
    ..
```

Unfortunately the order of instances is random. I like to sort by eg. instance-id.
I cant do a

```
Arrays.sort(instances);
```

because *Instance* is not implementing *Comparable*

Do I need to implement/extend it like

```
public class MyInstance extends Instance implements Comparable
```

or is there an easier way ?

thanks
Sven

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't sort a set. (Well, you can with a SortedSet but you get what I mean.)

```
List<Instance> listInstances = new ArrayList<Instance>(instances);
Collections.sort(listInstances, new Comparator<Instance>() {
   public int compare(Instance i1, Instance i2) {
      return i1.getInstanceId().compareTo(i2.getInstanceId());
   }
});
```